# SignalR. HubConnection The client method is not invoked from server

Tags: c#, signalr

Can anyone out there help me to understand

What is wrong in the following code that the client method is not invoked from server method using SignalR.

I am able to invoke the client method when the broadcast button is clicked. 
And also the event is fired when I run the selfInvoke code from a console application.

The server class resides in an CustomEvent handler in a different assembly.

Code for Chat Hub is as follows:

```
namespace MySample.Handler
{
    [HubName("chat")] 
    public class Chat: Hub
    {
        public void Send(string message)
        {
            Clients.addMessage(message);
            // I tried this code as well:
            // IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<Chat>();
           // context.Clients.addMessage("Hello world");
        }
    }
}
```

Source code of invoking the chat hub is as follows:

```
namespace MySample.Handler
{
    public static class SelfInvoke
    {
        public static void OnEvent()
        {
            var hubConnection = new HubConnection("http://localhost:48994");
            var chat = hubConnection.CreateProxy("chat");
            hubConnection.Start().Wait();
            string message1 = "Hai from OnEvent Handler!!!";
            chat.Invoke("Send", message1).Wait();
        }
    }
}
```

Index.aspx

```
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-0.5.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/signalr/hubs" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
          var chat = $.connection.chat;

          chat.addMessage = function (message) {
              $('#messages').append('<li>' + message + '</li>');
          };

          $("#broadcast").click(function () {
              chat.send($('#msg').val());
          });
          $.connection.hub.start();
        });
    </script>
  <input type="text" id="msg" />
  <input type="button" id="broadcast" value="broadcast" />
  <ul id="messages">
  </ul>
```

index.aspx.cs  [Code behind code..]

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
        SelfInvoke.OnEvent();
   }
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Regards
Vince

Comment: The javascript needs to be running and loaded to receive messages. Did you send the messages after the page was fully loaded and connected to the hub?

Answer (score 0):

Change your JavaScript client function definitions so they are:

`chat.client.XXX = function ...`

instead of:

`chat.XXX = function ...`

Also, change your call to the server to be:

`chat.server.send($('#msg').val());`

instead of:

`chat.send($('#msg').val());`